# Angular ui-router loads neither template nor controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use `ui-router` for moving between pages, without reloading.

Here is one of my `states`:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});

$stateProvider
.state('aboutBook', {
  url: '/book/about/:bookId',
  templateUrl: '/views/books/about-book.tpl.html',
  controller: 'AboutBookCtrl'
})
```

Here I have `ui-view` `div` in my `index.php` file.

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

When I go to the `/book/about/9874365942` page, I have both controller and template accessible, **but `ui-router` doesn't load neither template nor controller.**

**What can cause such behavior? How can I fix it?**

Note: `ng-include`, loads template just file

```
<div ng-include="'/views/books/about-book.tpl.html'"></div>
```

Update: `$stateChangeStart` and `$stateChangeSuccess` events aren't triggered as well.

Comment: did you check your console for errors?

Comment: yes, I did check console for errors :-). And there are no errors

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or a plunk?

Comment: No, because it will work in small demo app, however It is not working in my app and the question is "What can cause such behavior?".

Comment: do you have other routes that might interfere with this one? /book/about/id

Comment: You are using the html5 mode, so what is your php application serving when someone accesses the path /book/about/9874365942 on the server? How do you know if the angular application is even initialized? In your include sample, I assume you are loading your index.php file, right?